# Regarding planets capturing gases from space with their gravitational pull;

Tags: atmosphere, planetary-science, escape-velocity, planet-formation

We know most (or all) planets suffer [atmospheric escape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_escape).

Now, can planets gain atmosphere from drawing in gases drifting in space? Is there a formula for that?

Is there a cutoff point between gravity, temperature, and gas density where this two processes invert (i.e. the planet gains atmosphere with time).

Does this only happens during the accreation phase when the planetary system is forming?

Comment: This is a kewl question. Thanks. The escape velocity of low molecular weight molecules has been dealt with extensively, but not the flip side: capture of heavy molecules. Thanks for the post. I will follow with interest.